Automate creation of multiple tables based on groupby/filters from single data source
I am trying to automate the creation of a report and since I am new to power bi, I am unsure if my idea is possible.
I generate data in an excel spreadsheet and use it as my data source.
I need to group the data by multiple conditions: Counterparty, Product, Deal, Date and perform aggregations: Sum : Value.
Now, I want to filter the data essentially into multiple different tables and display each one.
Given this data:
Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Buy    01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Buy    01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00

I need to output something like this:
Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
                                           20.00

Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
                                           20.00

Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
fizz          buzz     Buy    01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Buy    01/01/24     10.00
                                           20.00

Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00
                                           20.00

I can manually do this however I have no clue how to split it into different tables.
Ideally, I would like this to be automated using DAX/Python. Is this achievable?
Note: I have achieved these results using python and pandas in Visual Studio, but I would like to use Power BI to visualize my results

Can you help me understand why you want to filter the data into multiple different tables? In Power BI, we can have one table then use slicers to only display specific data from that table. Would that suffice?

Yeah I was doing research, and slicers sounded promising.

@NickA When I say filter, in power bi I can manipulate the each column with a filter just like you would filter a columns in excel essentially. In my Instance I am grouping  (filtering) by the 4 columns I mentioned, which would return a subset of the original data. I need to dynamically display each subset with a table. In my example the first group is (foo, bar, Buy, 01/01/24)  and so on.

Slicers are the equivalent of filters in Excel. I would recommend going with one table and using 4 slicers (one for each column) to filter down the table as needed. Do you need help creating this or grouping your data in Power BI?
